# How to open device calendar from flutter app?

Tags: flutter, calendar, appointment

I want to open the local calendar by click on a button from flutter app in IOS and Android platform, with initial parameters such as title, description and date.
In fact, I need open `'Add Event'` of the calendar, directly from my app.

I've tried some packages like [device_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/device_calendar), but it needs to implementation own design for `add and edit event form`.

It is possible to open `new event` form of device calendar directly?

Answer (score 0):

For Android try this: `launchUrl(Uri.parse('content://com.android.calendar/time/123456789'))`
where launchUrl is [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

EDIT:

Good is plugin [add_2_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/add_2_calendar). It is open device calendar with that's options:

```
final event = Event(
          title: cart.title,
          description: description,
          location: 'Warsaw/Poland',
          startDate: DateTime.parse(dateString),
          endDate: DateTime.parse(dateString),
        );
        await Add2Calendar.addEvent2Cal(event);
```

where "Add2Calendar.addEvent2Cal" has opened calendar event (on IOS AppleCalendar, on Android GoogleCalendar or other default platform) with options above.